# SLES Apache Solr start.jar, Unable to access jarfile

Tags: java, apache, solr

I'm having some problems with starting the Apache Solr Search.

After installing java 7 on my SLES 11 64 Bit Server, I unpacked solr 3.6.1 to
/srv/apache-solr-3.6.0/

After this i wanted to start the software, but when i tried:

```
java -jar start.jar
```

the subfolder:
    /srv/apache-solr-3.6.0/solr/example/

I recieve the following error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile start.jar
```

? :-/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably downloaded the source version, which doesn't include the start.jar file, try this one: http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/lucene/solr/3.6.0/apache-solr-3.6.0.tgz

Comment: Sry for ticking u that late :P

Comment: Additional information: you can find all the Solr versions on https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/. Then download solr-<VERSION>.tgz instead of solr-<VERSION>-src.tgz

Answer (score 1):

This file is in server folder in `solr-5.3.1` so if you want to run the `start.jar` the  following steps are required:

1. Open Command Prompt from that directory where you extract the zip file
2. Go to you `solr-5.3.1` directory.
3. Open bin folder
4. Type `solr start -e cloud noprompt`

Comment: -bash: solr: command not found in 6.2.1, in  dir /Users/david/Documents/solr-6.2.1/bin

Comment: solr in bin directory is an executable file so try to run ./solr start

Answer (score 0):

I just removed solr9.0 and added solr8.7 and removed solr from path in environment variables , added java to path and JAVA_HOME variable