# SOLR: Facing issues in starting solr services

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene, search-engine

I have used java 1.9.0 and the path is correctly set in environment variable. Moreover,both Solr and java are in C drive. But its showing a consistent error:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
"Failed removing old solr logs"
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
"Failed archiving old GC logs"
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
"Failed archiving old console logs"
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
"Failed rotating old solr logs"
Error: Unable to access jarfile start.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI

Help me solve this error..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The critical error in the logs seems to be " Unable to access jarfile start.jar".

Maybe this can help [SLES Apache Solr start.jar, Unable to access jarfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818130/sles-apache-solr-start-jar-unable-to-access-jarfile)